# Why is GDScript not printing during this while loop?

Tags: while-loop, terminal, output, godot, gdscript

I am working with the following *while* loop in GDScript:

```
while tunnels_carved < num_tunnels:
    ...
    .
    .
    tunnels_carved += 1
    print("Generation at ", round(tunnels_carved / num_tunnels * 100), "%")
```

This is contained within a method for an object that `extends TileMap`.

This issue I'm having is that none of the calls to `print` send anything to the output stream until the entire *while* loop is completed; at which point it spits out every line at the same time. If the code encounters a break-point during the *while* loop, the `print` functions begin to work as expected. Is there a way to force GDScript to print these strings before moving to the next iteration of the while loop?

I don't think the rest of the code in the *while* loop is pertinent, but if it is, I would be be more than happy to share it.

**Edit**: I've noticed the strings do get printed to the OS terminal window at the appropriate time. I suppose this will do well enough. If anyone knows how to get the Godot Editor's console to display these strings at the appropriate time, please let me know.

Comment: It appears that there is at least an issue on github for a similar problem. That case got reopened many times. https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/61244. The second answer could at least be a hint, why the prints do not appear, till the function is done.

Comment: Is there any yield() command before the print()?